# Partitioning a disk on Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox, filesystem

My first post here, I am quite new to Linux but I want to learn more than just to use basic commands like cp and rm.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

In order to get better at Linux I started following a sort of step-by-step tutorial.

But I got stuck, I am not able to partition my disk.

By default I get a single disk called sda divided into 3 separate partitions: sda1 (primary), sd2 (extended) and sda5 (logical).

The first one is slightly over 500 MB and contains whatever files are necessary for booting the system.

The remaining two overlap, I guess the logical partition is "nested" within sda2.

Anyways, I did as instructed to remove the logical partition and create two separate ones in its place using the sudo fdisk command.

I used the following values while prompted: default, +5G; default, default.

Then I ran additional commands "sudo resize2fs dev/sda5" and "sudo resize2fs dev/sda6" but it read that there was nothing to change as far as aligning the new sizes with the filesystem goes.

I rebooted the machine as the changes were not reflecting after typing in "lsblk" and... I cannot boot... I reads error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>.

None of the partition is available when I try to access them with ls.

I tried allocating both dynamic and static storage while setting up the system but it does not matter.

All I try to do is partition a disk without breaking my system.

I will just mention that I previously tried that with parted and to the same result.

Any suggestions?

Is it even possible to partition a disk the standard way while running Linux on a VM?

Feel free to ask questions and thanks in advance.

Regards. Kamil

Comment: There is no need to create partitions when you install Ubuntu to VB.

Comment: Partitioning of a virtual hard drive is the same as partitioning of a physical hard drive. The basic properties of the drive from the point of view of the OS are the same. The virtual drive makes some tasks even easier: you can easily attach the drive to a different VM (to check or fix it) without moving a physical drive, you can change the size of the drive (but you must adjust the partitioning to use the new size)... --- Anyway, the easiest partitioning is during the installation. Later you need some additional knowledge. Removing partitions could have destroyed your existing volumes.

Comment: @pabouk Ukraine stay strong - Thank you for the time you took to answer my question.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Thanks for the answer.